# How to change font size, colour etc. when creating Text at loop

Tags: java

Creating gridpane and adding text from arrays and i like to change colour and sizes of font

```
GridPane text = new GridPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        text.add(new Text("text"), 0, i);
        // probably here to do something to change fonts size etc.  
    }
```

Comment: What is GridPane???

Comment: Assuming this is javafx, Did you try reading [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html)?

Comment: Please provide us some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of you want some help

Comment: @BackSlash I do not assume. But exceptions can be made, see my answer.

Comment: @EugenCovaci "I do not assume". Then realizes my assumption could actually be right, writes an answer and edits the comment. Cool :D

Comment: @BackSlash Now I realize assuming is cool :D

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html):

```
Text t = new Text(10, 50, "This is a test");
t.setFont(new Font(20));
```

... assuming this is Javafx.

Comment: i dont want to do this about 15 times Text t = new Text();

Comment: @Seppo Then don't do it.